# Eclipse cannot load resources directory (Build Path Problem)

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-2, maven

I found there is an exclamation mark in the icon of my project. I guess it is caused by the resources directory is not loaded.

Here is part of my .classpath file, anything can be wrong?

```
<classpathentry kind="src" path="src/test/java" output="target/test-classes" including="**/*.java"/>
  <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/java" including="**/*.java"/>
  <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/resources" excluding="**/*.java"/>
```

The problem Eclipse shows is

Project 'dingdong' is missing required source folder: 'src/main/resources'  dingdong        Build path  Build Path Problem

Comment: Check the Markers-view in your Eclipse for any build error details (Window -> Show view -> Markers)

Comment: Does the src/main/resources-directory actually exist in your hard drive? If so, try refreshing your project in Eclipse (select project root and hit F5). Also removing & re-adding the source folder to your build path might help, also you could try right-clicking your project root and selecting Maven -> Update project configuration  (I'm assuming you're using the m2eclipse-plugin)

Comment: Same error as in the Problems view. Java Build Path Problem. MIssing required source folder 'src/main/resources'

Comment: I am not using m2eclipse-plugin.

Comment: @esaj, it gets solved after refresh! Thanks a bunch! I have restarted the Eclipse, close project/open Project, why this step not refresh????

Comment: @esaj, how to removing &re-adding the source folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just adding this here if someone stumbles on the same question: The problem was solved by refreshing the project (Selecting the project root and hitting F5), see comments.

Eclipse does not refresh the workspace projects by default when starting up. You can add an start-up option (the flag is *-refresh*, see [here](http://help.eclipse.org/help33/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tasks/running_eclipse.htm) for details) for performing a global refresh of the workspace on startup. This will reconcile any changes that were made in the file system since the platform was last run.

Removing and re-adding the source folder to project Build path can be done like this:

- Right click on the source folder,
  select Build path -> Remove from
  build path
- Select the folder from the "normal" (non-source folder) -directory tree (usually shows way down in your project tree), right click the desired directory and select Build path -> Use as Source folder

Answer (score 0):

Refreshing the project, which is what the accepted answer suggests, failed for me.

Here is what I did to resolve this issue:

1. Right click , and then select `Build Path -> Configure Build Path... -> Order and Export`
2. Look for the src/main/resources folder in the entries list. Mine was called `<my project folder>/src/main/resources`.
3. Move `<my project folder>/src/main/resources` to the bottom of the dependency list by selecting it and clicking the button titled `Bottom`.

This resolved the issue for me. In my case, the `resources` entry was above the `src/main/java` and `src/main/test` entries, which seems to have been causing problems.